What is the context, in Sefer Yossipon, of this? “Because in their fury they killed an Ox” (Gen. 49)
The author is making a list of places where the LXX translators changed the wording and meaning.
The sixth, “Because in their fury they killed an Ox” (Gen. 49). That phrase was replaced for, “in their will they broke the Crib”. Lest the King should deride them and ask, “what hath a man to do with an Ox?”
It is an altered version of Gen 49.6, which describes Simeon and Levi. [credit: Harel, see below].  Does anyone know where this text came from?
Is this anything to do with Joseph, as per shur in the 49.22 - which I interpret as a misreading for shor - (and Deut 33.17 which corresponds to it)?
I'm also curious, though less so, about the change that was made to "crib". The word is ambiguous in English. (It can mean bed, cradle or cowshed.) What is the story behind that?
(I am aware that shor and evus occur together once: in Isa 1.3.)
If anyone has a copy of the Hebrew that would be extremely helpful. It's not in the Sefaria library.
I'm sure there are critical editions of Josippon which must address this puzzle. But I don't have access to any.
[Question edited in light of answer below.]

Welcome to Mi Yodeya.
You're using a modernized version of the 17th century edition of "The Abbreviated English Josippon: The Wonderful and Deplorable History of the Jews". As the editors of that volume stated themselves, the first section of the book was taken from older works (Josephus, Maccabees, etc.), which they found to be helpful to the readers. The passage you're quoting is from that section and doesn't appear in Josippon itself. I don't know from where exactly they chose to quote, but the list of verses changed by the 72 sages who authored the LXX appears in a number of Talmudic sources, chief among them Mekhilta de-Rabbi Yishmael 14:17:

"..."כיוצא בו כתבו אליו..."כי באפם הרגו שור וברצונם עקרו אבוס..."
My translation: "....similarly, they wrote for him [Ptolemy]..."for in their anger they killed an ox and when pleased they maimed a manger (can also be translated as "crib").

This also appears in Yerushalmi Megillah 1:9, Bavli Megillah 9a, Tractate Sefer Torah 1:9, Tractate Soferim 1:8, and a specific mention in Beresheet Rabbah 98:5 (mentions of other specific changes can be found in various sources).
As Rashi explains in his commentary on Megillah 9a, this change was made so that the king wouldn't be led to conclude that the ancestors of the Jews were bloodthirsty murderers.
I don't know exactly what you mean by the verse in this text being slightly different from the MT, but I'll assume you mean that the English wording is different from what you found on Sefaria. While it's not farfetched to imagine that the original author of Josippon had a slightly different Masoretic tradition, in this case it's not evidence of a different MT, as each translator chooses a different way of translation (and all the more so given that this section was not translated from Josippon but likely from one of the early printed [=re: standardized] editions of one of the above referenced works, or from a work that quoted such an edition).
As an aside, I believe the only critical edition of Josippon is David Flusser's edition, which is based on the oldest complete manuscript, MS Jerusalem. However, to my knowledge it cannot be accessed online for free (but vol. 1 can be found on the Kotar website and vol. 2 on Otzar Hachochmah). That said, many copies of Josippon can be found on Hebrewbooks, e.g. the editio princeps (can also be found on the NLI website). Text versions are also available on Wikitext (albeit incomplete) and the Maagarim website.

Thank you for this outstanding and helpful answer! (I was looking at the wrong verse.) More to follow.

Thank you to Harel13 for showing that the change to the Hebrew text compared to the Greek, is attested in the Talmud (various places) and has only been added to Josippon.
As it happens, the text of the LXX we have DOES differ from the MT, but it is not as described in the Talmud.
The text is Jacob's blessing (Gen 49). Specifically, his words to Simeon and Levi are a rebuke and a curse IMO. It appears to relate to their treacherous attack on Shechem, where they killed the men and enslaved the women. Afterwards, Jacob said: You have made me a stink to the inhabitants of the land (Gen 34.30).
Here is the text of Gen 49.6.
בְּסֹדָם אַל־תָּבֹא נַפְשִׁי בִּקְהָלָם אַל־תֵּחַד כְּבֹדִי כִּי בְאַפָּם הָרְגוּ אִישׁ וּבִרְצֹנָם עִקְּרוּ־שֽׁוֹר
In their counsel let not come my soul. In their assembly let not be joined my glory. Because in their anger they killed a man. And in their self-will they hamstrung an ox. (my trans)
εἰς βουλὴν αὐτῶν μὴ ἔλθοι ἡ ψυχή μου, καὶ ἐπὶ τῇ συστάσει αὐτῶν μὴ ἐρείσαι τὰ ἥπατά μου, ὅτι ἐν τῷ θυμῷ αὐτῶν ἀπέκτειναν ἀνθρώπους καὶ ἐν τῇ ἐπιθυμίᾳ αὐτῶν ἐνευροκόπησαν ταῦρον.
Into their counsel let not come my soul, and to their banding-together let not be fixed my LIVERS. Because in their anger they killed MEN; and in their desire they hamstrung A BULL. (LXX, my trans)
I like ἥπατά. It translates kaved liver instead of kavod glory. As the two clauses have parallel meaning, I interpret both "my soul" and "my liver" to mean "I", "my life".
LXX pluralizes the men killed (which fits the story). MT has only one victim.
LXX keeps singular the bull who was hamstrung. The greek word is very specific and means exactly that - to sever the sinew. Ikker is used that way in 4 other instances, but there it refers to chariot horses in war. Note that the Hebrew word more usually means "to uproot" and is connected with words meaning "descendant" and "barren".
Jerusalem Talmud Megilla 1.9.15 alleges the version presented to Ptolemy goes thus:
“For in their rage they slew a bull and in their will uprooted a trough"
כִּי בְאַפָּם הָֽרְגוּ שׁוֹר וּבִרְצוֹנָם עִקְרוּ אָבוּס
Evus "trough" connotes food and shelter - it's a shed as much as a manger. I came across it because of the greek φάτνη in Luke's infancy story, which translates it.
Although there is nothing in the usage in the Hebrew bible to suggest birth - only food and shelter - I do wonder if that was a pre-existing connotation.
(I am sticking my neck out, I know.)
There is no mention, in Gen 34 (the sack of Shechem) of hamstringing livestock. In fact it says Simeon and Levi took all the livestock, which makes sense. Why spoil when you can steal?
I think the only reason the LXX jumps to ἐνευροκόπησαν, is because of the other 4 instances, where the military logic is compelling.
In short, I think the more natural interpretation of the MT here is "uproot", or "deprive of issue".
I will be honest. I think the bull shur may refer to Joseph, who was either killed and/or deprived of issue. (cf. Gen 49.22. Deut 33.7). My intuition is that there may be an older version of the sack of Shechem, which still involves Simeon and Levi, but where the victim is not Hamor but Joseph. Joseph is deeply associated with Shechem, where he is buried.
This would explain the curious Hosea 6.9, where a murder is committed on the road to Shechem, with priestly and robber-band connotations. I also link it to Proverbs 1:10–18.
I am aware I am going out on a very long limb here. But I ask you to consider it..
As for Rashi's interpretation - that killing a bull makes the Jews seem much less bloodthirsty than killing a man - I remind you that in the account we have of the sack of Shechem, they kill ALL the men. Which LXX acknowledges: ἀπέκτειναν ἀνθρώπους (pl).
Killing one man and one bull is an odd way of describing the story in Gen 34. It actually makes more  sense if the man and the bull are the same. And how else to explain the curious reference to evus a manger? ...
This is a speculative interpretation, which may not convince. It provides the context of the original text. It's an explanation of the Talmudic amended text (which may once have been LXX), namely "kill a bull... ruin a crib" (my paraphrase). It is euphemistic, because it refers to the killing or castrating of a beloved culture hero. Like all euphemisms, it is intended both to disclose (to the wise) and to keep hidden (from others).
Please see Haral13's post above for the Talmud passages which attest to the altered text.

Hello @hedgehogful. Thank you for sharing your thoughts. The posting that you made as an answer to your question does not answer your question. It is a good and detailed comment to your question. Unfortunately, the format of the site does not allow for such posts. If the answer of Harel13 is not satisfactory for you, you may ask him questions in the comments. Alternatively, you may edit your original question to share your translations from the Greek text as well as additional comments that you may have, which Harel13's answer did not cover. Thank you.

@Harel 13. No, it isn't. It's an answer to the question I asked, using the information you provided.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review Many of your quotes are not sourced and one can prove them to be incorrect. The Tamud is vast, any reference must have an exact folio. The alternative readings may also be faulty given the mutitude of sources for Septuagint translations.

@Y DJ It is not a request for clarification from an author. It is my answer to the question "what is the context", which requires examination of the variants.

@Y DJ  I have added a Talmud citation. Re the LXX: How can my reading be "faulty"? According to what standard? You acknowledge there are variants. I only quote the text in STEP. I never attach more authority to a LXX reading beyond "this is the one we have". It is certain that the text was variable. "Many of your quotes are not sourced and one can prove them to be incorrect." Prove away. I am curious what you refer to. And what you mean by "incorrect".

A couple of notes on what you wrote: 1. איש (Ish), the Hebrew word for man, can also be understood in plural, a bit similar to how Man can also refer to Mankind in general. 2. שור, Hebrew for bull, is pronounced Shor, with an O. Shur, spelled the same in Hebrew but pronounced differently, means something else.

Ouch, I just realised that some of the confusion is entirely my fault, from re-drafting and not reading back. So, sorry. 2 important errors corrected.

Your 1) Ish. I know that, and LXX reads it that way. But I think of it as sing. meaning Man/kind, which doesn't apply here. This is the men of Shechem. 2) I am aware of shur/shor. My ESV has "branches run over the wall", which we know is not what the text is about. I actually hoped to be challenged on this, but my sloppy copy-editing made it unintelligible. To be clear, I consider 49.22 unsolved - but I am not among the first to have guessed that שור is bull and not wall. ;)

The Hosea connection is interesting. I never much though about it because it is in the "boring" section of the bible. The Chabad Tanach seems to make it about fishermen rather than robbers, though I can clearly see the word Gad, meaning troop and the word Shechecm. Interestingly, Gdudim in Yiddish is "gentiiles", according to Google.

As for your long limb, God took us out of Egypt with a Zeroa Netuya!

@Clint Eastwood  Hosea not boring! Fish hook is Rashi. intprt of chakkah. Agree abt Gad - Gilead, gedud. In Asenath, the evil pair are Dan and Gad (not Simeon, Levi). Tho Kohenim fits Levi better.

What are you referring to about Asenath, Gad, and Dan?

@ClintEastwood en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_and_Aseneth .The 2nd part - I suspect the story is very old - It's like a crude mini-Iliad. Dan and Gad are suborned to kill Asenath, after Simeon and Levi refuse.
